# How to delete a row of table in haml code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Working on haml code. I want to delete a row or simply disappears it from table if a condition is met. Is there any way possible to accomplish this task?

```
              - if post_name.present?
                %td= 'Present'
              - elsif post_name.blank?
                %td= 'none'
              - else
                %td= ''
```

This is just an example. Here if **post_name.blank?** is **true** then I want to delete or disappear that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't render it.  You likely have a `%tr` entry, right?  I imagine you could delete it with...

```
- @rows.each do |row|
  - if row.post_name.present?
    %tr
      %td = 'Present'
      (any other columns you want included)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to disappear the row you have to add condition on `tr` & not `td`.

```
- if post_name.present?
  %tr
    %td= 'Present'
    %td= 'Some other columns'
```